# Creating 3 pandas series as pie charts in one plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm setting up a figure to display 3 pie charts. Data for the charts come from 3 separate pandas series. I suppose I could merge the series into a df and create subplots via that df but I doubt it's needed.

My current code generates 3 pie charts. But they all overlap. I'm confused about how to arrange them.

```py
S19E_sj = (BDdf.loc[BDdf['GRPCODE'] == 'SJ3219'])['Result'].value_counts()
S19E_ge = (BDdf.loc[BDdf['GRPCODE'] == 'G1932'])['Result'].value_counts()
S19E_jl = (BDdf.loc[BDdf['GRPCODE'] == 'JLG1930'])['Result'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
S19E_sj.plot.pie()
S19E_ge.plot.pie()
S19E_jl.plot.pie()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you can try something like this. Create a figure containing 3 subplots arranged in a row, and then assign them individually to your three pie chart commands

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize = (8,6))
S19E_sj.plot.pie(ax=axes[0])
S19E_ge.plot.pie(ax=axes[1])
S19E_jl.plot.pie(ax=axes[2])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```